# Decomposing a random variable with random mean into a sum

Tags: correlation, covariance, random-variable, gaussian-mixture-distribution, function

I have two random variables:

- $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2+1)$.
- $Z$, a gaussian with mean $X$, distributed so that $E_{X,Z}[(X-Z)^2]=s^2.$

We know that: $$s^2\geq\sigma^2+1 \Leftrightarrow Z \text{ is independent of } X .$$

We also know that $Z=X+W$, for some random variable $W$.

What is the distribution of W, with parameters in terms of $\sigma^2$ and $s^2$ (that is, *not other random quantities*)?

Comment: This question is not readable because (a) "$W$" is defined both as a random variable and as a "variance", which is self-contradictory, and (b) the tag phrase "in terms of $\sigma$ and $s$ for all these things to hold" makes no sense.  Please edit this post accordingly.  BTW, what is the basis for your "only sane" assertion?  It doesn't seem to be true, so I suspect you haven't described all the assumptions you are making.

Comment: "sane" is a substitute for _saying_ or maybe _sayin'_ ?

Comment: Fixed both things. It should be a real question now.

Comment: OK--but your first "we know that" clearly is untrue.  $s^2$ could be any nonnegative value whatsoever. Moreover, you can take $Z=X+W$ with $W$ normal, independent of $X$, with mean $0$ and arbitrarily large variance $s^2$. This $Z$ is *never* independent of $X$.

Comment: All that means is that $W$ is not normal and independent of $X$... we have all this information about X, Z and W and their relationships, and we want to use it to find the distribution of $W$

Comment: It isn't the things that you know that will kill you, but the things that you know but just ain't so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question, and all the responses by the OP, seems not to jibe in various
ways.

> - $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2+1)$.
> - $Z$, a gaussian with mean $X$,

I assume this means that the *conditional* distribution of $Z$, given that
$X = x$, is Gaussian with mean $x$, that is, $E[Z\mid X = x] = x$. As is
known, by $E[Z\mid X]$ we mean a *random* variable that happens to be a *function*
$g(X)$ of $X$ -- in fact, $E[Z\mid X] = g(X) = X$ in this instance.
The law of
iterated expectation tells us that $E[g(X)]$, the *expected value* of 
$g(X) = E[Z\mid X]$,
is miraculously equal to $E[Z]$, that is,
$$E\left[E[Z\mid X]\right] = E[g(X)] = E[X] = 0 = E[Z]$$
allowing us to conclude that the *unconditional* mean of $Z$ is $0$.

What about the *conditional* variance of $Z$ given that $X = x$?  The OP 
only says that

> $E_{X,Z}[(X-Z)^2]=s^2.$

which I take to mean that $E[(Z-X)^2] = s^2$. So applying the
law of iterated expectation in the opposite direction, we can write
$$s^2 = E[(Z-X)^2] = E\left[E[(Z-X)^2\mid X]\right].$$
 But, given that
$X = x$, the conditional variance of $Z$ (a random variable whose
conditional mean, given that $X=x$, happens to be $x$) is just $E[(Z-x)^2]$.
In other words, $E[(Z-X)^2\mid X]$, a random variable that is a function of $X$,
is a *degenerate* random variable having constant value $s^2$. We conclude
that
$\operatorname{var}(Z\mid X) = s^2$, or equivalently, that

> conditioned on $X = x$, the *conditional* distribution of $Z$ is Gaussian
>   with mean $x$ and variance $s^2$.

Turning to the *unconditional* variance of $Z$, we recall the conditional
variance formula:

> the unconditional variance is the sum of the mean of the conditional
>   variance and the variance of the conditional mean.

Since the conditional variance is always $s^2$, its mean is also $s^2$,
while the conditional mean is $X$ whose variance is given to be
$\sigma^2+1$. It follows that
$$\operatorname{var}(Z) = s^2 + \sigma^2+1.$$

Finally, the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X$ is Gaussian,
and since $X$ is also Gaussian, we have that $X$ and $Z$ are
*jointly* Gaussian. Both also have mean zero. The 
*linear* minimum-mean-square-error (MMSE) estimator of $Z$ in terms of
$X$ is
$$\hat{Z} = \frac{\rho\sigma_Z}{\sigma_X}X$$
where $\rho$ denotes the correlation coefficient. Since the random variables
are jointly Gaussian, the linear MMSE estimator must be
the same as the *unconstrained* MMSE estimator $E[Z\mid X]$ which
we already know has value $X$. Consequently,
$$1 = \frac{\rho\sigma_Z}{\sigma_X} 
= \frac{\rho\sqrt{s^2+\sigma^2+1}}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad \rho = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2+1}{s^2+\sigma^2+1}}$$

---

Thus, making reasonable assumptions about unsaid things, we can say that

- $Z$ and $X$ are zero-mean jointly Gaussian random variables with
  variances $\sigma_Z^2 = s^2 + \sigma^2 +1$ and $\sigma_X^2 = \sigma^2+1$,
  and correlation coefficient 
  $\displaystyle \rho = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2+1}{s^2+\sigma^2+1}}$.
  Note that 
  $$\operatorname{cov}(Z,W) = \rho\sigma_Z\sigma_X = \sigma^2+1$$
- The conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X = x$ is $\mathcal N(x,s^2)$.

---

It follows that $W = Z-X$ is also a zero-mean Gaussian random variable
whose variance is
$$\operatorname{var}(W) = \operatorname{var}(Z)
+ \operatorname{var}(W) - 2\operatorname{cov}(Z,X)
= s^2+\sigma^2+1 + \sigma^2+1 - 2(\sigma^2+1) = s^2.$$
Furthermore, $W$ and $X$ are jointly Gaussian random variables
whose means and variances are listed above. Also,
$$\operatorname{cov}(W,X) = \operatorname{cov}(Z-X, X)
= \operatorname{cov}(Z,X) - \operatorname{var}(X)
= (\sigma^2+1) - (\sigma^2+1) = 0$$
showing that $W$ and $X$ are *independent* random variables.

---

In summary, a reasonable model is

> $$Z = X+W, \quad W \sim \mathcal{N} (0,s^2), 
> \quad X \sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma^2+1),
> \quad W, X ~ \text{independent}.$$ 
>   
>   $\qquad\qquad Z \sim \mathcal{N} (0,s^2 + \sigma^2+1)$. 
>   $\quad Z$ and $X$ are **not** independent random variables.
>   
>   Conditioned on $X = x$, $Z = x+W \sim \mathcal{N}(x,s^2)$

---

The OP's assertion (in continued defiance of Moderator @whuber's remarks)
that

> We know that $s^2\geq\sigma^2+1 \Leftrightarrow Z \text{ is independent of } X .$

is incorrect. Whether or not $s^2$ exceeds $\sigma^2+1$, $Z$ and $X$
are **not** independent random variables.